# Unable to use EntityType with FormFactory

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm currently working with **Symfony** but I ran into troubles with forms.

I have an entity named `Categories`. In my form, I have a request selecting all categories having an attribute `gamme` corresponding to my variable `$gamme`.

`$categories` is an array containing categories, as expected. I want to be able to select a category in my form.

But a the display, I only have one choice available.

Do you know where is the problem ?

This is my code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('gamme', ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => array('AUT' => 'AUT', 'FFE' => 'FFE', 'FSI' => 'FSI', 'FSE' => 'FSE', 'FME' => 'FME')))
            ->add('designation')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('critereRech1')
            ->add('critereRech2')
            ->add('critereRech3')
            ->add('critereRech4')
            ->add('taxonomie')
            ->add('articleAssocie1')
            ->add('articleAssocie2')
            ->add('articleAssocie3')
            ->add('qteMaxCde')
            ->add('publication')
            ->add('codeArticle');
        $builder->get('gamme')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event){
```

$form  = $event->getForm()->getParent();
            $gamme = $event->getData();
            $this->addCatgeorieField($form, $gamme);

        }
    );
}

/**
 * Rajoute un champs catégorie au formulaire
 * @param FormInterface $form
 * @param $gamme
 */
private function addCatgeorieField(FormInterface $form, $gamme){

    $categories = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Categories')->findBy(["gamme" => $gamme]);
    dump($categories);

    $builder = $form->getConfig()->getFormFactory()->createNamedBuilder(
        'codeCategorie',
        EntityType::class,
        null,
        [
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Articles',
            'placeholder' => 'sélectionnez la catégorie',
            'required' => false,
            'choices' => $categories,
            'auto_initialize' => false
        ]
    );
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event){
            dump($event->getForm());
        }
    );
    $form->add($builder->getForm());
}  </code></pre>

This is my current result. But instead of one categorie I should have 34 categorie:

[image]

This is the result of dump($categories) :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my mistake. In this code :

```
[

           'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Articles',

           'placeholder' => 'sélectionnez la catégorie',

           'required' => false,

           'choices' => $categories,

           'auto_initialize' => false

       ]
```

At 'class', instead to write 'Articles' I have to write 'Categories' because I want display a different instance of my entity `Categories`.

Thank you all for your answers.